# How to get hex string of md5sum in Phoenix sqlline?

Tags: hbase, apache-phoenix

md5() returns a BINARY(16), how can I convert it to a string in sqlline?

http://phoenix.apache.org/language/functions.html#md5

Answer (score 0):

Phoenix doesn't provide out of the box function to convert BINARY(16) to HexString.

But you can write your own custom UDF(i.e. in java) to convert Binary-to-hex and import with following guidelines.

https://phoenix.apache.org/udf.html

https://phoenix.apache.org/udf.html#How_to_write_custom_UDF